# Reading consoleText URL from within a running build only returns first 10000 lines

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy

I have a groovy code that reads from the current consoleText and do some jobs. When I run the code from the IDE, it works perfectly but when I run it as a part of a step in Jenkins, it only reads 10000 lines of the total which is approximately 2.8 million lines. The code to read from the console is:

```
url.withReader { bufferedReader ->
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                          //do something
            }
}
```

The url is

> ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText

Comment: Maybe this is a memory problem or some jenkins limitation? You mentioned that this is a step a build - is the build finished? Or maybe it hangs waiting on console?

Comment: do you have any error or it just stops reading exactly after 10K lines? could you remove all the code from the while-loop except just counting lines to be sure the problem is not in the code?

Comment: The build in `${BUILD_URL}`, has it already completed by the time you're reading the console output?

Comment: To make things clear the code was working 2 weeks back but from last Monday it stopped working after 10000 line. The ${BUILD_URL} is the running build url. There are no errors the while loop exits exactly after 10000 lines

Comment: when the Jenkins build is in progress, the response for the .../consoleText URL maxed out at 10000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The `.../consoleText` URL will not "grow" automatically -- it just provides a "snapshot" of console data that's available at query time.

So, if you GET that URL for a build *while that build is still running*, then you will only see part of the console log. The amount that you see will depend on the time when you issue the GET -- and possibly it will also depend on the status of some buffers.

If this used to work better in the past, then you probably moved the point in time when you tried to read the console.

Comment: The code is only reading the console text after a particular stage as Post condition. So the console text should have the full log till that stage.

Comment: I suppose that depends on buffering and on Jenkins' internal handling of the console log URL API... Could you try to trigger a new, second job ("B") from your job "A", and read "A"'s console from that?